# how to generate random shuffled number in tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensorflow

I want to generate numbers from 0 to a specific number and then randomly shuffle those numbers.
I get some value from a tensor `total = tf.Variable(BCIsize[0]+BCRsize[0]+BCOsize[0], dtype = tf.int32)`. For example if the value of total is 20 I want to generate numbers from 0 to 19.

I tried to generate using `reqnum= tf.random_uniform([1,total],minval=0,maxval=total,tf.int32)`
but it `Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(1, ?), dtype=int32)`.

I need to generate equal numbers and then shuffle with the value that comes as 'total' variable.
I expect output randomly something like [8,14,1,3,5,11,6,9,10,19,12,13,2,15,7,16,17,4,18]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tf.range` to create list, then `tf.random_shuffle`

```
idx = tf.constant(20)
idx_list = tf.range(idx) # 0~19
shuffle = tf.random_shuffle(idx_list)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = sess.run([idx_list, shuffle])
```